# smartgwt ListGrid Filter not working after upgrading the 3.0 to 6.0 version

Tags: smartgwt

Recently upgraded smartgwt version from 3.0 to 6.0 and found listgrid filters are not working properly.

Below are steps to reproduce the issue,

```
1.All the Records are loaded from server to the listgrid.
2.Performing filtering in below scenarios

i.Selecting some value in filter,its filtering properly based on the selection
ii.now again i am reselecting the empty option(not selecting any think in filter) then it should list all the records into grid but its not showing anythink in grid(its failing here)


3.the same think is happening in case of other filter like text field when i am clearing the entered text,its not listing any records
```

I have used `setShowFilterEditor`,`setFilterOnKeypress` method.I am not able to figure out what causing this issue,If any body knows this issue please let me know how to fix this?

Note: In Datasource api of SmartGWT 6.0 version , setCacheAllData api is modified but i am not using this api in my listgrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved after taking the latest smartgwt jar (I was using Version `v11.0p_2016-07-23/LGPL Deployment - 2016-07-23`) replaced with `LGPL Deployment 2017-01-19` jar.Its a `smartgwt` issue.